# Can I disable element from changing css style for a while?

Tags: jquery, css, intervals

I've got a div#element that I'm changing css style in interval using jquery.

```
var i = 0;

function changeStyle() {

    $("#element").css("left",i+1);

}

setInterval("changeStyle()",500);
```

How do I stop element from changing the style for a while? Is there something like `$("#element").stop();` function that enables me to disable element from changing anything on it?

I don't want any other solution for this problem, I just want to know if there's anything like stop() function.

Comment: Please NEVER pass a string to `setInterval()` - use a function instead: `setInterval(changeStyle, 500);` or, if you want to pass arguments to the function, `setInterval(function(){ someFunc('with', 'args'); }, 500);`

Comment: Why is it wrong to pass a string?

Comment: It is just like using `eval()` - and when dealing with arguments it'll get really ugly and you risk opening javascript injection holes.

Comment: I see, thank you, I'll take care of that next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method to accomplish that is to create an `!important` CSS rule:

```
// Lock the `left` style in a fixed state, say "0px"
$('<style id="my-style">#element{left:0 !important;}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

If the current element does not have an ID, you can temporary assign one.
When the element has to be "unlocked" again, use:

```
$('#my-style').remove();
```

Comment: Note: I assumed that you cannot/don't want to modify the original code. You can also define a `<style>` element beforehand, and disable/enable it by setting the DOM `disabled` property (`true`/`false`). If you have full control over the code, consider using `clearInterval`, as shown by adeneo.

Answer (score 0):

It probably should be :

```
var i = 0;
function changeStyle() {
    $("#element").css("left",i+1);
}

var T = setInterval(changeStyle,500);
```

to stop it do:

```
clearInterval(T);
```

and to start it again, just repeat:

```
var T = setInterval(changeStyle,500);
```